# How to split an assembly file(.dll file) into many assembly files

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I am building a projects by C#. It contains many folders, each folder represents for a function. Now I want to make a .dll file for each of them. Is there any tools can help me to do it?
And after that I want to merge them together. Is there any solution for me to do it?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you elaborate on particular reason why do you want to do this ?

Comment: A folder for a function? Do you want to split them and then merge them? `bool yes = !!true;`

Comment: Because i want to build an installation package for each function. And the function will be installed to the main program (that's why i want to merge the function to the application) when run the installation package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for modules in `.NET`. Where module is a file (not a DLL) with self sufficient (from structure perspective) content which can be read and executed by `CLR` virtual machine into machine code.

Read this for detailed explanation: [How to: Build a Multifile Assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/build-multifile-assembly)

You will need to do a little command line execution, no direct visual studio support, afaik.

Comment: A module isn't a _"...dll file for each of them..."_ but I agree it may be one possible interpretation...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Infact, I didnt' say DLL. It's just a file.

Comment: I see, that's why it's a good catch but I still don't understand what OP wants (split bigger project into multiple dll then merge them together again?)

Comment: Thanks for your help very much. I think I should write a small app to build the whole folder into a .netmodule file.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to move from a folder structure to a project structure. Each project will automatically have its own .dll file. Then you can have a central project that has references to each of them.

It would be a good idea to group together certain code files by project for other reasons too. Suppose you have a lot of extension methods that could easily be re-used for other coding projects. You might separate these classes into a `Util` project / namespace for easy re-use and access across other projects.

Comment: I also think about this solution, but there are so many functions in that project. So there will be many projects that i have to create when i do this way. That's why i try to find another solution